# Adding new column to multiple data frames at the same time

Tags: r, function

I have 7 datasets DF1..DF7 & al of them have the data in the following format:

```
Lowerbound  Upperbound
738.5349709 2418.259919
734.5215381 2160.478003
1826.381884 2753.12212
452.3846655 3013.798816
542.6524558 863.0564862
399.4240401 2862.168099
```

I want to calculate the difference between the 2 columns & add a 3rd column to all the data sets at the same time & call it "interval" .I used the following code:

```
filenames <- names(which(sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame)))
for(i in seq_along(filenames)) {
x <- get(filenames[i])
for(j in 1:length(x))
{
x$Interval[[j]] <- ((x$upper_bound[[j]] -x$lower_bound[[j]])/x$actual[[j]])/2
}
assign(filenames[i], x)
}
```

The column "interval" gets generated but the values populated are wrong     :numeric(0) is the result that I get to see in the new column.

Can someone suggest an improvement? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get all the datasets in a `list` with `mget`, use `lapply` to loop over the `list` elements, create a new column 'Interval' using `transform` by getting the difference between 'Upperbound', 'Lowerbound' and dividing by 'actual' (not seen in your data, but I guess it is already there)

```
lapply(mget(paste0("DF", 1:7)), transform, 
                Interval = ((Upperbound - Lowerbound)/actual)/2)
```

Comment: Could you explain this part more? (mget(paste0("DF", 1:7))

Comment: @Mox `paste0("DF", 1:7)` create a vector of strings i.e. object names as strings, and `mget` will return the value of each of the string in a `list`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is *way* more complicated than it needs to be. You can simply subtract two vectors in R:

```
data$interval = data$Upperbound - data$Lowerbound
```

Or, using `within`:

```
data = within(data, interval = Upperbound - Lowerbound)
```

Now apply this to all your data frames:

```
filenames = mget(paste0('DF', 1 : 7))
filenames = lapply(filenames, function (data) within(data, interval = Upperbound - Lowerbound))
```

(Note that this will create a *new* list of your data frames rather than modify the original ones.)

Better yet, merge all the data into a single data frame with one additional column that specifies the origin.

Answer (score -1):

I did this differently. Maybe not the most efficient but this allows you to modify the data frames in a loop:

1: get a vector of data frames you want to modify with  `ls(pattern = "YOUR-PETTERN")`  . In this case, your pattern is "DF", assuming you do not have any other object that have the pattern "DF"
Make sure that with ls() you are only getting the objects you want to modify!
Then this should be the code. This will modify your objects

```
for (i in ls(pattern = "DF")) {      
  assign(i,transform(get(i),Interval = ((Upperbound - Lowerbound)/actual)/2)
}
```

`assign` is just assigning what ever you are doing, in this case `transform` to the character vector that in this case is each data frame at the time.

Hope this is helpful.