# Is it possible to update multiple datasets using lapply in R?

Tags: r, dataset, lapply

I am currently trying to update multiple datasets by adding a new column to each of them.

I did read the solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741612/adding-new-column-to-multiple-data-frames-at-the-same-time).
However running

```
lapply(list(annual_2022_v2, bottom_2022_v2, q1_2022_v2, q2_2022_v2, q3_2022_v2, q4_2022_v2, top_2022_v2), transform, start_hour = hour(started_at))
```

only printed the correct output, but didn't update or added the new column to my original datasets.

To test it on an individual dataset I did,

```
lapply(list(q1_2022_v2), transform, start_hour = hour(started_at)).
```

Although it did print the correct dataset with the new column, it didn't update it.

I am trying to figure out the "optimal" way to be able to write some sort of loop, rather than hard-coding 8 different datasets, such as

```
q1_2022_v2$start_hour <- hour(q1_2022_v2$started_at)
q2_2022_v2$start_hour <- hour(q2_2022_v2$started_at)
q3_2022_v2$start_hour <- hour(q3_2022_v2$started_at)
q4_2022_v2$start_hour <- hour(q4_2022_v2$started_at)
```

I also see solutions using Map() and cbind(), but I am confused on how they work.

---

I eventually decided not to complicate things and just work with one dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't assign it, `lapply`'s return value is lost. `lapply` is not a `for` loop, it does functional programming. What you see printed is its return value.

Start with putting these datasets into a list. I strongly suspect they all have the same structure, which means they should have never been separate, i.e. put them into the list when they are created/imported.

```
all_2022_v2 <- mget(ls(pattern = glob2rx("*_2022_v2")))

all_2022_v2 <- lapply(all_2022_v2, transform, start_hour = hour(started_at))
```

You should probably `rbind` the four datasets and have q as a grouping column.

Comment: Hello Roland, I guess I am confused of how to properly store my datasets. Essentially I wanted to make them separate to see the difference between each datasets, since they cover in increments of 3 months of a whole year ie: is there a difference of customers within q1 vs q3?

I do have a dataset called annual_2022_v2, should I just get rid of the q1, q2, q3, q4? and just work with one big dataset since all of the structure are the same?

Comment: Yes, you can always subset your original dataset on the fly if needed or you can transform it into wide format or use a `group_by` operation. It depends on the specific goal. Never split a dataset but if you do, use `split` which returns a list with the subsets.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I think you have saved me hours of unneeded workload in the future. I already implemented your suggestion and decided to just work with annual_2022_v2

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to assigned that code to new data try this

```
df<-lapply(list(data), transform, newcol = somevalue)
```